# Symfony 4.1 custom validator with EntityManagerInterface not working

Tags: validation, symfony4

I want to validate some variable outside of the $form->isValid() but i get the following error message:

> Too few arguments to function
>   App\Validator\Constraints\ContainsTestValidator::__construct(), 0
>   passed in ****\vendor\symfony\validator\ConstraintValidatorFactory.php
>   on line 43 and exactly 1 expected

Controller:

```
class TestController extends AbstractController
{
    public function validate(Request $request)
    {
        $string= $request->request->get('data');

        $validator = Validation::createValidator();
        $constraint = new Assert\ContainsTest();
        $violations = $validator->validate($string, $constraint);
    }
}
```

ContainsTest :

```
class ContainsTest extends Constraint
{
    public $message = '"{{ string }}" is not valid.';
}
```

ContainsTestValidator:

```
class ContainsTestValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    private $entityManager;
    /**
     * @param EntityManager $entityManager
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        /* some code */
    }
}
```

has anyone an idea how to initialization the EntityManagerInterface ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it. I had the same problem.
Here is a hint https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/27760
But what is you really need for your `TestController` inject `Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface` in constructor.
After that use this interface instead of `Validation::createValidator();`
Here how it should be:

```
class TestController extends AbstractController
{
    private $validator;
    public function __construct( ValidatorInterface $validator)
    {
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    public function validate(Request $request)
    {
        $string= $request->request->get('data');

        $validator = $this->validator;
        $constraint = new Assert\ContainsTest();
        $violations = $validator->validate($string, $constraint);
    }
}
```